# Gtk# ListStore in EntryCompletion is not visible when application runs in X server

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I have created EntryCompletion.
Following is the code ,

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::EntryCompletion> completion = Gtk::EntryCompletion::create();
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> refCompletionModel = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_columns);

std::list<string> mylist;
mylist.push_back("Alen");
mylist.push_back("Asian bro");
mylist.push_back("Bob");
mylist.push_back("Bob medal");

Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;
std::list<string>::iterator itr = mylist.begin();

for(; itr != mylist.end();  ++itr)
{
  row = *(refCompletionModel->append());
  row[m_columns.m_col_name] = *itr;
}

completion->set_text_column(m_columns.m_col_name);
completion->set_model(refCompletionModel);
cmbSearch->set_popdown_strings(mylist);
cmbSearch->get_entry()->set_completion(completion);
```

When I run my binary in Gnome-desktop environment, its working fine.But when I run in X server, typing inside combo box entry does not show the auto detected strings.

Run command on X server,
**/usr/bin/xinit ./binaryName ../conf/confFile -- :2**

Thanks for any help.